# Separating Business Workflow from Django Application

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow

I've got a Django App where I need to follow different workflow for different inputs.

I receive an input parameter with the data payload over the `POST` endpoint. Based on the input, I need to fire different functions, process the data accordingly and finally save it in the data store.

One option is to write `if-else`, however writing `if-else` is difficult in maintaining as the code grows.

For eg:-

```
If input1, then function1(), process1(), save1()

elif input2, then function2(), process2(), save2()
```

I've looked into [Intellect](https://github.com/nemonik/Intellect), [django-viewflow](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow) and many other business-rule libraries, but not sure about the recommended way of doing it.

It'll be helpful if anyone can provide me a dummy example or an open-source project via which I can understand the implementation of the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not building a huge application, right?

So to focus on the root requirement which is different processes for different inputs, you can create multiple objects extended from a Base object `Processor`, such as `AppleProcessor` or `OrangeProcessor`. All of them share the same interfaces.

And then in your logistical part, you can create a dictionary looks like:

```
processors = {"Apple": AppleProcessor, "Orange": OrangeProcessor}
```

Then it is easy to take it in use:

```
processor = processors.get(input)
processor.process(*some_needed_args, **some_needed_kwargs)
result = processor.get_result()
```

This is just a simple solution, if you have more restrictions, it may becomes much more complicated.

Comment: Any idea on how to use Django-viewflow for it? I'm not completely sure on how to do it?